# Как присоединить один массив к другому несколько раз?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Как присоединить один массив к другому несколько раз через цикл?
Нужно к gridAreas присоединить несколько раз массив arr и чтобы результат был в newGridAreas.

Мой скрипт работает правильно, если this.state.rowsCount равен 1 или 2. Если this.state.rowsCount > 2, он ведет себя некорректно.

Если this.state.rowsCount = 2, то newGridAreas =

```
0: "sources auto"
1: "clicks auto"
2: "shows auto"
3: "conversion-price auto"
4: "price auto"
5: "conversion auto"
6: "sales auto"
7: "sources_twin_1 auto"
8: "clicks_twin_1 auto"
9: "shows_twin_1 auto"
10: "conversion-price_twin_1 auto"
11: "price_twin_1 auto"
12: "conversion_twin_1 auto"
13: "sales_twin_1 auto"
```

А если this.state.rowsCount = 3, то newGridAreas =

```
0: "sources auto"
1: "clicks auto"
2: "shows auto"
3: "conversion-price auto"
4: "price auto"
5: "conversion auto"
6: "sales auto"
7: "sources_twin_2 auto"
8: "clicks_twin_2 auto"
9: "shows_twin_2 auto"
10: "conversion-price_twin_2 auto"
11: "price_twin_2 auto"
12: "conversion_twin_2 auto"
13: "sales_twin_2 auto"
```

А мне нужно, чтобы если this.state.rowsCount = 3, то newGridAreas =

```
0: "sources auto"
1: "clicks auto"
2: "shows auto"
3: "conversion-price auto"
4: "price auto"
5: "conversion auto"
6: "sales auto"
7: "sources_twin_1 auto"
8: "clicks_twin_1 auto"
9: "shows_twin_1 auto"
10: "conversion-price_twin_1 auto"
11: "price_twin_1 auto"
12: "conversion_twin_1 auto"
13: "sales_twin_1 auto"
14: "sources_twin_2 auto"
15: "clicks_twin_2 auto"
16: "shows_twin_2 auto"
17: "conversion-price_twin_2 auto"
18: "price_twin_2 auto"
19: "conversion_twin_2 auto"
20: "sales_twin_2 auto"
```

Вот мой скрипт:

```
  pasteTableArticlesTwins(){
      const table = document.querySelector('.table'),
            tableArticles = document.querySelectorAll('.table__article');
      const gridAreas = ['sources auto', 'clicks auto', 'shows auto', 'conversion-price auto', 'price auto', 'conversion auto', 'sales auto'];
      
      let newGridAreas;
      
      for(let z = 1; z <= this.state.rowsCount; z++){

          const arr = gridAreas.map((i) => 
         { 
              return i.replace(/\s+/, `_twin_${z-1} `)
         
         });
          
          newGridAreas = [...gridAreas, ...arr]
          
          
          
          if(this.state.rowsCount === 1){
              newGridAreas = '';
              newGridAreas = ['sources auto', 'clicks auto', 'shows auto', 'conversion-price auto', 'price auto', 'conversion auto', 'sales auto'];
          }
          
          console.log(newGridAreas)
      }
}
```

Comment: `newGridAreas = Array.of([1,2],[3,4],[5,6]).flat()`

Comment: Вот такой результат выдаёт:
(6) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Comment: так разумеется. В `Array.of(...)` можно засунуть любое кол-во нужных массивов и выполнить `flat()`. А можно просто создать массив и запушить в цикле свои таким образом `newArray.push(...arr1); newArray.push(...arr2); и т.д`